# Marketing Cloud register domain or private domains for Senders

Tags: marketing-cloud, custom-domain, deliverability

I need to verify a domain to use different senders in Marketing Cloud (companydomain.com). We already have a Sender Authentication Package that is a subdomain of our domain (sap.companydomain.com), but we need to use some emails as sender which they are from our domain (user1@companydomain.com, user2@companydomain.com …). These senders changes a lot and sometimes we need to use Dynamic Senders, so I saw two options: use either a Private Domain or a Domain Registration. Can anybody help me with two doubts about it:

1. Private Domains allows you to send mail from an authenticated domain (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000318538&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1) This means that the send with a sender from a registered a Domain will not be authenticated or it depends on the configuration in our domain?
2. Can We use our domain as a private domain? Or it needs to be a subdomain (a not existing domain)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will be able to send from the top level domain of your company (e.g. as john@company.com) by purchasing and configuring a Private Domain on your company.com domain. Assuming you already have your SAP in place on e.g. marketing.company.com. Those need to be within same top domain as DMARC will otherwise fail.

As in most cases for SAP, the subdomain in delegated to Salesforce name servers, and all DNS configuration is managed by their team. This is obviously not possible with regards to you top domain, so you will be provided with a set of DNS records to be updated in your existing zone of company.com

Also managing RMM in SFMC will not be possible, as MX records for company.com already point to your existing mail servers

Comment: Thank you @Lukas Lunow, but regarding this last part (managing RMM), it will not be possible only with domain or with both? (domain and subdomain) I ask this because we have the RMM configured for our SAP domain

Comment: And, if you allow me a second question, register domain is not possible? (or will we have some authentication problems?) I need to relate because is the free option

Comment: RMM will still be possible on SAP domain, just not on your top domain. Using private domain is much preferred, from a deliverability perspective- as only this option will ensure your domain has the correct SPF and DKIM records