# Private Domain - Without SAP

Tags: marketing-cloud, setup, custom-domain

I'm configuring an account that includes one PRIVATE DOMAIN and one DEDICATED IP, but it does NOT have SAP.

In this case, what is the best practice to configure and use private domain?
Should I use one subdomain specific for Marketing Cloud? For example: email.company.com

Does the private domain allows to use a subdomain (even if I don't have SAP)?

Then, should I delegate the domain to the servers of Marketing Cloud? (ns1.exacttarget.com, ns2, etc)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "best practice" is probably to get an SAP which provides both of these things plus branding :)

SAP is a package containing a Private Domain, not a different thing.

Should I use one subdomain specific for Marketing Cloud? For example: email.company.com

- yes, you want to use a subdomain for sendouts that only SFMC is using so that you have full control over reputation.

Does the private domain allows to use a subdomain (even if I don't have SAP)?

- Don't fully understand the question. As written, SAP doesn't do anything but contain a Private Domain. So, Private Domain on its own can be set up for a subdomain like `email.company.com`. It is an *option* to use a top-level domain like `company.com`, Private Domain does not force you to do that.

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000318538&type=1

[Marketing Cloud register domain or private domains for Senders](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/314234/marketing-cloud-register-domain-or-private-domains-for-senders)

- Private domain is used for either sendouts or cloudpages, SAP on the other hand covers all; when set up for email sendouts, PD on `email.company.com` does not automatically provide sub-subdomains like `cloud.email.company.com`  for cloudpages
  or link (`view.email.company.com`) and image wrapping (`image.email.company.com`). It is purely for authenticated sendouts.

Then, should I delegate the domain to the servers of Marketing Cloud? (ns1.exacttarget.com, ns2, etc)

- yes, you delegate the subdomain the same way as you would like when you go through the set up of an SAP. That part of the SAP where you delegate *is the included private domain* - you are doing the exact same thing.

Comment: Thank you for all the explanation.
I'm working on one account that has private domain, but it does not include SAP. So I was confused about setting the account.